# static protocol extensions generates Illegal Instruction compiler error

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-extensions

I have read up on the [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) available in Swift and was wondering if static `protocol extensions` are supported? I know that instance methods can be used in a `protocol extension`.

I was wanting to create a protocol for my repository, along with an implementation of that repository:

#### Repository protocol

```
public protocol NoteRepositoryProtocol {
    func getAllNotes() -> [Note]
}
```

#### Repository implementation

```
class NoteRepository : NoteRepositoryProtocol {
    func getAllNotes() -> [Note] {
        return [Note]()
    }
}
```

Then in order to maintain loose coupling within my application, I wanted to create the repository through a factory. I was trying to be clever and attach a static method to my protocols like so:

```
public extension NoteRepositoryProtocol {
    public static func createInstance() -> NoteRepositoryProtocol {
        return NoteRepository()
    }
}
```

I know this can be done if I drop the `static` keyword here, but i really wanted it to be static so I could do this:

```
func test_note_repository_returns_a_valid_note_repository() {
    let repository = NoteRepositoryProtocol.createInstance()
}
```

Now when I want to change my repository implementation out, I could do so by updating my protocol extension factory method. The other alternative is to create an actual factory to handle this, but I like the idea of a factory method existing on the type itself.

When I compile this, I am given the following complier error:

> Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4
>
> warning: initialization of immutable value 'repository' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
>           let repository = NoteRepositoryProtocol.createInstance()
>           ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
>           _
>   not existential
>   UNREACHABLE executed at 
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.38.1/src/swift/lib/SILGen/SILGenExpr.cpp:3311!
>   0  swift                    0x0000000106760e0b llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
>   1  swift                    0x000000010676154b SignalHandler(int) + 379
>   2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9440ef1a _sigtramp + 26
>   3  swift                    0x0000000106d5aa2e FirstTarget + 60550
>   4  swift                    0x0000000106761346 abort + 22
>   5  swift                    0x000000010671ae21 llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 481
>   6  swift                    0x00000001049b503c swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOpenExistentialImpl(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, llvm::function_ref) + 2588
>   7  swift                    0x00000001049c0ba1 swift::Lowering::RValue swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOpenExistential(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, (anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter::visitOpenExistentialExpr(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext)::$_0) + 65
>   8  swift                    0x00000001049b6f00 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 4864
>   9  swift                    0x00000001049af49f swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitExprInto(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::Initialization*) + 303
>   10 swift                    0x00000001049a0dd8 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::visitPatternBindingDecl(swift::PatternBindingDecl*) + 232
>   11 swift                    0x0000000104a021fa swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtEmitter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 362
>   12 swift                    0x0000000104a02085 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitStmt(swift::Stmt*) + 21
>   13 swift                    0x00000001049ca136 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 390
>   14 swift                    0x000000010496d3ed swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 253
>   15 swift                    0x0000000104a0833c (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 956
>   16 swift                    0x0000000104a07ede swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 30
>   17 swift                    0x000000010497028b swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 571
>   18 swift                    0x000000010497106f swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional, bool, bool) + 703
>   19 swift                    0x000000010497128b swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&, llvm::Optional, bool) + 123
>   20 swift                    0x000000010477a691 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef, int&) + 9153
>   21 swift                    0x00000001047780b3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char const*, void*) + 2515
>   22 swift                    0x000000010477428f main + 1983
>   23 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff934fb5c9 start + 1
>   24 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000048 start + 1823492736

Can you not use static methods in a protocol extension?

#### Update

I removed the unit test assertion to improve the root of the problem in the example source. The issue is that the compiler doesn't like my invoking the static method on the protocol.

Comment: To me this looks like a bug.

Comment: I'll take a look at creating a bug on it.

Answer (score 1):

a non optional never can be nil

```
public static func createInstance() -> NoteRepositoryProtocol? {
    return NoteRepository()
}
```

Comment: The line doing the nil check wasn't the compiler error though. If I comment out it, I receive the same compiler error. I'll give your answer a shot

Comment: That solved my issue perfectly. Do you know the technical reason why I'm forced to return an optional in this scenario? Nil check aside.

Comment: Hmm, after restarting Xcode, it seems that making it optional was not the issue. I was able to leave my code as-is and recompile without any issues, with a non-optional factory method. Not sure what was up with Xcode.

Comment: if its not an optional you cannot test for nil. thus i proposed to make it optional

Comment: Heh, sorry. I had made changes to my code overnight, one of which included making that extension protocol a struct. When I converted it back to a protocol extension, making it optional or non-optional did not solve that compiler error. I updated my OP to remove the nil check, as this continues to be a problem after I remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275):

> Protocols do not actually implement any functionality themselves.
>   Nonetheless, any protocol you create will become a fully-fledged type
>   for use in your code.

Hence, you can not directly call static methods of a protocol.